# SQL phpmyadmin update table if null

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

I have an early question and it has been answered where I wanted to update a certain row on the table if same row from another table is updated.
its working fine but when that certain row is deleted, the entry stays in the other table.
Please help how to delete that also.

Here is the current trigger where account_name is copied from main_accounts to payments table.

```
UPDATE payments a  
JOIN main_accounts b ON a.payment_method = b.payment_method  
SET a.account_name = b.account_name
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: So you want to delete a entry from `payments` table which is not present in `main_accounts` table

Comment: Yes Sir. You are right.
That column is the "account_name"

The trigger I am using now does this:
When I update main_accounts table, account_name is copied to account_name in payments.
But when I delete the entry in the account_name from main_accounts, account_name in payments remain.

Please help.. thank you so much..

Comment: Why don't you try using UPDATE DELETE cascade.

Answer (score 0):

You need a `Delete` with `Sub-Query`

```
DELETE FROM payments
WHERE  payment_method NOT IN (SELECT payment_method
                           FROM   main_accounts)
```

But i would suggest you to have `On Delete Cascade` and `On Update Cascade` which will make your life easier

Comment: Hello Sir..
Thank you, the code worked however, it deleted the whole row.
I wanted to just delete the entry.

Comment: My bad it should be `payment_method` check now. Don't use the word `SIR`

Comment: It is really deleting the whole row Sir.
I don't know what is missing.
when I run the query, phpmyadmin asks a confirmation if I wan to run the delete query and it will delete the whole row.

I was also reading some help sites but I am not sure if there's something like:
update table join table2 on column = empty/null

i don't really know.

Comment: @MarkJuni Yes it will delete the entire row. Ok it is slightly confusing. Just add **sample data** from both the tables which should cover your **scenario** and the **expected output**.